# MySQL partitioning and temporary tables

Tags: mysql, partitioning, temp-tables

A large table (~10.5M rows) has been causing issues lately.  I previously modified my application to use temporary tables for faster selects, but was still having issues due to UPDATE statements.  Today I implemented partitions so that the writes happen more quickly, but now my temporary tables error.  Its purpose is to group events, placing the first event ID of a set in the EVENT_ID column.  Example: writing 4 events beginning at 1000 would result in events 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, all with an EVENT_ID of 1000.  I have tried to do away with the UPDATE statements, but that would require too much refactoring, so it is not an option.  Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `all_events` (
  `ID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EVENT_ID` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `EMPLOYEE_ID` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `QUANTITY` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `OPERATORS` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SECSEARNED` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'for all parts in QUANTITY',
  `SECSBURNED` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `YR` smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT (year(curdate())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`YR`),
  KEY `LAST_UPDATE` (`LAST_UPDATE`),
  KEY `EMPLOYEE_ID` (`EMPLOYEE_ID`),
  KEY `EVENT_ID` (`EVENT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17464583 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`YR`)
(PARTITION p2015 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2017 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (2019) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN (2020) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN (2021) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2021 VALUES LESS THAN (2022) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2022 VALUES LESS THAN (2023) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2023 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Now in my application when running a report the statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ape ENGINE=MEMORY AS
SELECT * FROM all_events
WHERE LAST_UPDATE BETWEEN '2022-05-01 00:00:00' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Produces the error: `'Specified storage engine' is not supported for default value expressions.`

Is there a way to still use temporary tables with `ENGINE=MEMORY`, or is there another high performance engine I can use?  The statement worked until the partitioning was implemented.  InnoDB is the only engine my tables can be in due to the MySQL implementation, and it has been InnoDB since before partitioning.

Edit: When removing `ENGINE=MEMORY` it does work, but running `SHOW CREATE TABLE` tells me that it's using InnoDB.  I would prefer the performance increase of MEMORY vs InnoDB.

Second Edit:
The MySQL server has been crashing 2 to 3 times daily, and every time I catch it I find this error:

```
TRANSACTION 795211228, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 13, locked 13
LOCK WAIT 866 lock struct(s), heap size 106704, 4800 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 5032986, OS thread handle 140442167994112, query id 141216988 myserver 192.168.1.100 my-user Searching rows for update
UPDATE `all_events` SET `EVENT_ID`=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE `EVENT_ID` IS NULL
RECORD LOCKS space id 30558 page no 16 n bits 792 index EVENT_ID of table `mydb`.`all_events` trx id 795211228 lock_mode X
```

It's running Galera Cluster with 3 nodes.  Node 3 is the main, becomes unavailable, and 1 comes offline to resync 3.  I fail over to 2 and we're usually good until it catches up, but it's causing downtime.  The temp tables I'm using are for faster reads, the partitioning is my attempt at improving write performance.

Third edit:
Added example SELECT - note there are fields not in the table definition, I reduced what was displayed for simplicity of the post, but all fields in the SELECT do in fact exist.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allpe AS
SELECT * FROM all_events
WHERE LAST_UPDATE BETWEEN ? AND ?;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ap1 AS SELECT * FROM allpe;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ap2 AS SELECT * FROM allpe;

SELECT PART_NUMBER, WORKCENTER_NAME, SUM(SECSEARNED) AS EARNED, SUM(SECSBURNED) AS BURNED, SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, (
        SELECT SUM(ap1.SECSEARNED)
        FROM ap1
        WHERE ap1.PART_NUMBER = ape.PART_NUMBER AND ap1.WORKCENTER_ID = ape.WORKCENTER_ID
    ) AS EARNEDALL, (
        SELECT SUM(ap2.SECSBURNED)
        FROM ap2
        WHERE ap2.PART_NUMBER = ape.PART_NUMBER AND ap2.WORKCENTER_ID = ape.WORKCENTER_ID
    ) AS BURNEDALL
FROM allpe ape
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?
GROUP BY PART_NUMBER, WORKCENTER_ID, WORKCENTER_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID
ORDER BY EARNED;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE allpe;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE ap1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE ap2;
```

Fourth edit:
Writing inside of stored procedure - this is not in a loop, but multiple rows can come from multiple joins to employee_presence, so I cannot get the ID and store it for writing subsequent rows.

```
INSERT INTO `all_events`(`EVENT_ID`,`LAST_UPDATE`,`PART_NUMBER`, `WORKCENTER_ID`,`XPPS_WC`, `EMPLOYEE_ID`,`WORKCENTER_NAME`, `QUANTITY`, `LEVEL_PART_NUMBER`,`OPERATORS`,`SECSEARNED`,`SECSBURNED`)
SELECT NULL,NOW(),NEW.PART_NUMBER,NEW.ID,OLD.XPPS_WC,ep.EMPLOYEE_ID,NEW.NAME,(NEW.PARTS_MADE-OLD.PARTS_MADE)*WorkerContrib(ep.EMPLOYEE_ID,OLD.ID),IFNULL(NEW.LEVEL_PART_NUMBER,NEW.PART_NUMBER),WorkerCount(NEW.ID)*WorkerContrib(ep.EMPLOYEE_ID,OLD.ID),WorkerContrib(ep.EMPLOYEE_ID,OLD.ID)*CreditSeconds,WorkerCount(NEW.ID)*WorkerContrib(ep.EMPLOYEE_ID,OLD.ID)*IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, GREATEST(NEW.LAST_PART_TIME,NEW.JOB_START_TIME), now()),0)
FROM employee_presence ep WHERE ep.WORKCENTER_ID=OLD.ID;
UPDATE `all_events` SET `EVENT_ID`=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE `WORKCENTER_ID`=NEW.ID AND `EVENT_ID` IS NULL;
```

Comment: Do the writes really run any faster?  What Select benefits from the temp table?  Is that benefit more than the cost of creating the temp table?  Let's see the Select.

Comment: I am not creating a temp table for writes, and don't believe that would actually work.  I edited the question with the error related to writes that is actually crashing the server.

Comment: Eh?  UPDATE `all_events` SET `EVENT_ID`=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE `EVENT_ID` IS NULL -- How many rows will that be?  Can't you get the ID _before_ inserting all those rows?

Comment: I am not the original dev, and of course I would have done it a different way, but now we're here...  Anyways, see third edit for example SELECT and fourth edit for writing.  I was surprised to find that EVENT_ID IS NULL never misses, but this has been in production since 2016 and has worked flawlessly.

Comment: What version number of MySQL?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.21-26.4 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Wsrep Server - GPL)

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose to read the following [link from dev.MySQL.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

> You cannot use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... LIKE to create an empty
> table based on the definition of a table that resides in the mysql
> tablespace, InnoDB system tablespace (innodb_system), or a general
> tablespace. The tablespace definition for such a table includes a
> TABLESPACE attribute that defines the tablespace where the table
> resides, and the aforementioned tablespaces do not support temporary
> tables. To create a temporary table based on the definition of such a
> table, use this syntax instead:
>
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl LIMIT 0;

So it seems the correct syntax for your case will be:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ape
SELECT * FROM all_events
WHERE...
```

Comment: I removed ENGINE=MEMORY and it worked.  The confusion is that it did work in the OP before partitioning, but not after.

Comment: @MaKR by the way. Are you expecting the future dates in `LAST_UPDATE`? If not you'd better use `WHEN LAST_UPDATE >= '2022-05-01' ` instead of a more comlicated `BETWEEN `.

Comment: These are user-entered parameters on an HTTP form, dynamically generated SQL, and parameterized statements.  The range is typically beginning of day to current, yesterday, or week to date.  Occasionally reports will run over a full calendar month.

Comment: I also have the ALTER TABLE in a PHP-generated script I'll run on cron to dynamically create new partitions on Dec 31 each year

Answer (score 1):

In the current issue the problematic column is `YR smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT (year(curdate()))`. This DEFAULT value is not legal for a column which is used in partitioning expression. The error will be "Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed ...".

---

And only when you fix this by removing the partitioning then you'll receive an error "'Specified storage engine' is not supported for default value expressions".

`CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` inherits main columns properties from source tables.

In the current issue the problematic column is `YR smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT (year(curdate()))` again. The column in temptable must inherit main properties, including DEFAULT expression - but this expression is not allowed for `MEMORY` engine.

Comment: I got that error on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), but found another SO post that suggested year(curdate()) was not timezone dependent and it worked.  I couldn't even get to the point of creating the column in the first place.  The state of the issue now is only that I am forced to use InnoDB temp tables and not MEMORY, which will degrade read performance on reports, but I still have the partitioning working which improves write performance.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, the expression default does not work with the MEMORY storage engine.

One solution would be to remove that default from your `all_events.yr` column.

The other solution is to create an empty temporary table initially as an InnoDB table, then use ALTER TABLE to remove the expression default and convert to MEMORY engine before filling it with data.

Example:

```
mysql> create temporary table t as select * from all_events where false;

mysql> alter table t alter column yr drop default, engine=memory;

mysql> insert into t select * from all_events;
```

Comment: The `YR` column is there to create the partitioning condition, and it has to be populated at the time of INSERT for the partition to be selected correctly.  It also has to be part of the PK or I get: Ignoring error 'A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function (prefixed columns are not considered).' on query.

Comment: Then you might like to use the second solution I wrote above.

Comment: I can see where that might work...  I don't like it because it's messy, but I may attempt it.  Thank you

Comment: Well you could reduce it to two steps if you use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and specify the full table definition, instead of relying on an implicit definition by the result of the SELECT. You have to admit if you have very specific and differing requirements for the base table and the temporary table, you can't expect it not to be "messy."

Answer (score 1):

**Sufficient?**  If I am not mistaken, this is equivalent to what your `SELECT` finds (no temp tables needed):

```
 SELECT  PART_NUMBER, WORKCENTER_ID, WORKCENTER_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID,
         SUM(SECSEARNED) AS TOT_EARNED,
         SUM(SECSBURNED) AS TOT_BURNED,
         SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOT_QUANTITY
    FROM  all_events
    WHERE  EMPLOYEE_ID = ?
      AND  LAST_UPDATE >= '2022-05-01'
    GROUP BY  PART_NUMBER, WORKCENTER_ID, WORKCENTER_NAME;
```

For performance, it would need this.

```
INDEX(EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_UPDATE)
```

Also, removing the partitioning might speed it up a little more.

**else**  (Notes on other fixes to the path you have taken)

Since `yr` is not needed, avoid it by changing '*' to a list of needed columns in

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ape ENGINE=MEMORY AS
SELECT * FROM all_events
WHERE LAST_UPDATE BETWEEN '2022-05-01 00:00:00' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

WHERE ap2.PART_NUMBER = ape.PART_NUMBER AND ap2.WORKCENTER_ID = ape.WORKCENTER_ID

Add this composite index to `all_events`:

```
INDEX(PART_NUMBER, WORKCENTER_ID)
```

That will probably suffice to make the query fast enough without the temp tables.
`Also add that`allpe` after building it.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `WITH` instead of needing the two extra temp tables.

Comment: Using CTE syntax has only ever degraded performance vs temp tables on MySQL - that was my method of optimization that works on IBM DB2.  The reason is it confuses MySQL's optimizer, while IBM DB2 does not have an optimizer.  Anyways, I just added the partitioning yesterday and have already seen a marked performance by adding it, with the only side effect being the loss of ENGINE=MEMORY, but still a net boost (2 min queries now take <10 sec).  I'd like to have the best of both worlds, though.  YR is the condition for which partition, so I probably could remove it, maybe 1M rows per partition?